# ReactQuill library functionalities

Tags: reactjs, react-quill

I am building a math text editor using the reactQuill library and I want that when I click on the formula icon on the toolbar (that is already provided by the library) the mathKeyboard that I created becomes visible.

But apparently, the ReactQuill library does not provide a straightforward way to customize the toolbar button behavior like a function onClick or something.

Is there any solution to do so without changing the library?

Because my project got big and I have no time to start again from scratch.